# How to handle MVI side effects in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am writing Flutter application and have the following `Widget` hierarchy:

`ParentWidget` class:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        // some deep class hierarchy
        children: [
            ChildWidget(...),
            TextButton(
                ..., 
                onPressed: () {
                     // notify `ChildWidget` here
                }
            )
        ]
     );
)
```

I am using MVI patterns heavily and would like to have reusable solution to handle cases like:

- display snackbar
- render dialog

Those events must be handled inside `ChildWidget`.

A `ParentWidget` needs to signal one-shot action to the `ChildWidget`. A `ChildWidget` can be `StatefulWidget` which can have some interactive `From` with `TextFormField`s and I would like to trigger input validation.

How should `ChildWidget` listen to one-shot event and handle the action just once?

How should `ParentWidget` notify the `ChildWidget` to handle one-shot action?